# Counting the number of times a similar text value occurs in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have a vector of names as follows :

```
                  Aaditi Behal   
                  Aaditi Behal    
                  aamir jilani   
                  Aarti khorwal  
                   AARTI VERMA
                  AARTI VERMA
                  AARTI VERMA
             Aarti Vilas Panse   
               astha Saxena  
               Aastha Saxena    
                 ABDUL GAFOOR   
                ABDUL GAFOOR 
                ABDUL GAFOOR    
                ABDUL GAFOOR    
                ABDUL GAFOOR     
                ABDUL GAFOOR    
                ABDUL GAFOOR
```

I have used  `dplyr` and its `count()` function and `table` function  but it gives me the following result

```
                  Aaditi Behal  1  
                  Aaditi Behal  1  
                  aamir jilani  1
                  Aarti khorwal 1 
                   AARTI VERMA  2
                  AARTI VERMA   1
             Aarti Vilas Panse  1 
               astha Saxena     1
               Aastha Saxena    1
                 ABDUL GAFOOR   6  
                ABDUL GAFOOR    1
```

As the similar text it has counted as different word. I want the output like this

```
                  Aaditi Behal  2  
                  aamir jilani  1
                  Aarti khorwal 1 
                   AARTI VERMA  3
             Aarti Vilas Panse  1 
               astha Saxena     2
                 ABDUL GAFOOR   7
```

Comment: Probably due to leading/trailing whitespace... please use `dput()` to post your sample data... also: take a look at `trimws()`

Answer (score 0):

Just strip the leading and trailing white spaces. You can use `stringr::str_extract` to do this indirectly by extracting the character-whitespace-character construct from your original string instead. Counting the instances of your strings thereafter should yield the correct result. You don't really need to use table here.

Since you haven't given us any data to work with, I've illustrated this with some made up data below.

```
library(stringr) #I am assuming you have dplyr and tidyr loaded

df <- data.frame(mya = c("  A A ", "B A", "C A  ", 
                         "A A   ", " B A ", "C A"), 
                 myb = c(1:6), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  count(mya)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   mya          n
#   <chr>    <int>
# 1 "  A A "     1
# 2 " B A "      1
# 3 "A A   "     1
# 4 "B A"        1
# 5 "C A"        1
# 6 "C A  "      1

df %>% 
  mutate(mya = str_extract(mya, "\\w[\\s]+\\w")) %>%
  count(mya)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   mya       n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 A A       2
# 2 B A       2
# 3 C A       2
```

Of course, this does not preclude that your data has other oddities that may be preventing them from being counted properly.

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, `base::trimws()` can also be used here as follows:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(mya = trimws(mya, which = "both")) %>% 
  count(mya)

#Or as  df$mya <- trimws(df$mya, which = "both")

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   mya       n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 A A       2
# 2 B A       2
# 3 C A       2
```